# How to return a std::function object of member function which define with parameter packs?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I want to define a member function which can be returned the `std::function` object of another member function. In general, it is very easily. But if that member function is defined by parameter packs, I don't know how to do it.

I wrote some code as follow,

```cpp
class Example {
  public:

  template<typename... Args>
  double getSome(Args... args) {
    // do something
  }

  template<typename... Args>
  std::function<double(Args...)> getSomeFun() {
        return std::bind(&Example::getSome<Args...>, this);
  }

};
```

That's look like correctly, unfortunate. When I call `getSetArgsFunction()` at `main()` method, I get a lot of error information. At `main()` method, my code as follow,

```cpp
int main() {
  Example e;
  e.getSomeFun()(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
}
```

I try to compile it, but `gcc` print some errors as follow,

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::function<double()>) (double, double, double)’
```

So, what should we do?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for @Quentin, but his/her proposal also can't solve the problem. 
Unabridged and minimal example code as:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Example {
  public:

  template<typename... Args>
  double getSome(Args... args) {
    for (auto x : {args...}) {
      std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
  }

  template<typename... Args>
  std::function<double(Args...)> getSomeFun() {
        return std::bind(&Example::getSome<Args...>, this);
  }

};

int main() {
  Example e;
  e.getSomeFun<double, double, double>()(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
}
```

And errors infomation is:

```
In file included from test2.cpp:14:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_check_arity<double (Example::*)(double, double, double), Example*>’:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:854:12:   required from ‘struct std::_Bind_helper<false, double (Example::*)(double, double, double), Example*>’
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:875:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = double (Example::*)(double, double, double); _BoundArgs = {Example*}]’
test2.cpp:29:25:   required from ‘std::function<double(Args ...)> Example::getSomeFun() [with Args = {double, double, double}]’
test2.cpp:36:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:841:7: error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member
       static_assert(_Varargs::value
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::function<double(Args ...)> Example::getSomeFun() [with Args = {double, double, double}]’:
test2.cpp:36:40:   required from here
test2.cpp:29:58: error: could not convert ‘std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = double (Example::*)(double, double, double); _BoundArgs = {Example*}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<double (Example::*(Example*))(double, double, double)>](((Example*)this))’ from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, double (Example::*)(double, double, double), Example*>::type {aka std::_Bind<double (Example::*(Example*))(double, double, double)>}’ to ‘std::function<double(double, double, double) 
’
         return std::bind(&Example::getSome<Args...>, this);
```

Comment: Your declarations require the call to be `e.getSomeFun<double, double, double>()(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);`. Do you want to defer creating the pack until it can be deduced from the 3 `doubles` with which you call the `std::function`?

Comment: Are you always going to immediately invoke the functional object returned by `getSomeFun`? If so, why this intermediate step of returning a functional? If not, maybe you could rewrite your example so that the invocation is not in the same expression as the call to `getSomeFun`? (Also, you may want to try compiling the code you post to get rid of typos. An online compiler could be useful for that; there is a list of online compilers on the [C++ tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).)

Comment: thanks, I update code and error info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bind you need to put placeholder arguments:

```
std::bind(&Example::getSome<Args...>, this,
    std::placeholders::_1,
    std::placeholders::_2,
    std::placeholders::_3
);
```

You need to put an amount of placeholer equal to the amount of arguments your function will need.

I suggest using a lambda in that case, since variadic placeholders are not a thing:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::function<double(Args...)> getSomeFun() {
    return [this](Args... args) {
        return getSome(args...);
    };
}
```

Also if you can affort constructing `std::function` at the call site, you can use deduced function return type to get rid of the `std::function` overhead in the places you call that and don't need a `std::function`:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto getSomeFun() {
    return [this](Args... args) {
        return getSome(args...);
    };
}
```